# Where are logs stored?

Tags: log, logging, privacy

AFAIK applications in Ubuntu track activity and errors beyond what is covered by the "Privacy" setting. (Including, for example, login/logout/shutdown times.) Where are these logs stored?

Comment: Almost all of the logs are stored in `/var/log`. You could use the *Log File Viewer* to view them nicely if you want to.

Comment: @nitstorm thanks - you could make that an answer?

Comment: Most welcome :) And done :)

Answer (score 7):

Almost all of the logs are stored in `/var/log`. Example: `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/dmesg`, etc..

You could use the *Log File Viewer* to view them nicely if you want to.